# c# Find the Longest Continuous Subarrays first and last elements Indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, continuous

In the inputs first row, there are two numbers the first one is the amount of rows *N* and the second one is a limit *K*. I have to find the first and last element's indexes of the longest continuous subarray which's elements are greater than *K*.

*(There are lots of inputs with different numbers, but they have the same base.)*

The example input is:

```
7 20
18
23
44
32
9
30
26
```

So the *N* is 7 and *K* is 20, in this case there are 2 continuous subarrays which would be correct: [23, 44, 32] and [30, 26], but I only need the longer ones indexes.

Therefore the output is:

```
1 3
```

I have split the first row, so i have the *N* and *K*, I have added the remaining rows in an array H[ ]. Now I just have to find the longest continuous subarray and get the first and last element's indexes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] fRow = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int N = int.Parse(fRow[0]);
            int K = int.Parse(fRow[1]);
            int[] H = new int[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                H[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```

And I'm stuck here, if someone could help me I would greatly appreciate their assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like homework, but an interesting challenge none the less. Here's one way of doing it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] fRow = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int N = int.Parse(fRow[0]);
    int K = int.Parse(fRow[1]);
    int[] H = new int[N];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        H[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    int greatesRangeStartIndex = -1;
    int greatestRangeEndIndex = -1;
    int greatestIndexSpan = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // Find the first array item that meets the criteria.
        if (H[i] > K)
        {
            var rangeStartIndex = i;

            // Continue spinning through the array while we still meet the criteria.
            do
            {
                i++;
            } while (i < N && H[i] > K);

            var rangeEndIndex = i - 1;
            
            // Determine the width of our current range and check if its our largest one.
            // If the range is the biggest so far, store that as the current largest range.
            var indexSpan = rangeEndIndex - rangeStartIndex + 1;
            if (indexSpan > greatestIndexSpan)
            {
                greatesRangeStartIndex = rangeStartIndex;
                greatestRangeEndIndex = rangeEndIndex;
                greatestIndexSpan = indexSpan;
            }
        }
    }

    // Report out the results.
    // Not part of the requirements, but will remove false reporting of the criteria being in index position 1.
    if (greatesRangeStartIndex == -1 && greatestRangeEndIndex == -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"No values in the array were greater than {K}.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{greatesRangeStartIndex} {greatestRangeEndIndex}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks the most efficient, also the only answer which correctly parses all `int`s first, instead of parsing them within the loop

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (could be improved a lot with LINQ, but i suppose this is an introduction exercise of some sorts, so i'll stick to this):

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] fRow = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int N = int.Parse(fRow[0]);
            int K = int.Parse(fRow[1]);
            int[] H = new int[N];
            int firstIndex = 0;
            int lastIndex = 0;
            int subarraySize = 0;

            int firstIndexTemp = 0;
            int lastIndexTemp = 0;
            int subarraySizeTemp = 0;
            bool arrayContinues = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                //Read the newest index
                H[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                /*If arrrayContinues is true, and the current value is higher than the threshold K,
                  this means this is the continuation of a subarray. For now, the current value is the last index value
                  */
                if (H[i] > K && arrayContinues)
                {
                    subarraySizeTemp++;
                    lastIndexTemp = i;
                }
                /*If arrrayContinues is false, but the current value is higher than the threshold K,
                  this means this is the first index of a new subarray
                  */
                else if (H[i] > K)
                {
                    subarraySizeTemp = 1;
                    firstIndexTemp = i;
                    arrayContinues = true;
                }
                /*If we reach this statement, the current value is smaller than K,
                 * so the array streak stopped (or was already stopped by a previous smaller value)
                 */
                else
                {
                    arrayContinues = false;
                }

                /* We're only interested in the largest subarray,
                 * so let's override the previous largest array only when the current one is larger.
                 */
                if(subarraySizeTemp > subarraySize)
                {
                    subarraySize = subarraySizeTemp;
                    firstIndex = firstIndexTemp;
                    lastIndex = lastIndexTemp;
                }

            }
            /*Let's print our result!*/
            Console.WriteLine($"{firstIndex} {lastIndex}");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers work out but you can use something simpler like this;

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    var n = int.Parse(input[0]);
    var k = int.Parse(input[1]);

    var startingIndex = 0;
    var endingIndex = 0;

    var temporaryIndex = 0;

    var items = new int[n];

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        items[i] = value;

        if (value < k)
        {
            temporaryIndex = i;
            continue;
        }

        var currentSize = i - temporaryIndex;
        var currentBiggestSize = endingIndex - startingIndex;

        if (currentSize > currentBiggestSize)
        {
            startingIndex = temporaryIndex + 1;
            endingIndex = i;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Biggest Subset's Start and Ending Indexes: {startingIndex} {endingIndex}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Option:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Example(new string[] { "7","20"},new string[] { "18", "23", "44", "32", "9", "30", "26"});
}

static void Example(string[] arr,string[] values)
{
    int N = int.Parse(arr[0]);
    int K = int.Parse(arr[1]);

    int counter = 0;
    int most_succesfull_index_yet = 0;
    int most_succesfull_length_yet = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (int.Parse(values[i]) > K)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (counter > most_succesfull_length_yet)
            {
                most_succesfull_length_yet = counter;
                most_succesfull_index_yet = i - counter;
            }

            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    // For last index
    if (counter > most_succesfull_length_yet)
    {
        most_succesfull_length_yet = counter;
        most_succesfull_index_yet = N - counter;
    }

    var bestStart = most_succesfull_index_yet;
    var bestEnd = most_succesfull_index_yet + most_succesfull_length_yet -1;

    Console.WriteLine(bestStart + "," + bestEnd);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, keeping indexes of the longest match, and displaying the max length, indexes, and rows values at the end.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = @"7 20
18
23
44
32
9
30
26";
            var rows = data.Split("\r\n");
            var frow = rows[0].Split(" ");
            int N = int.Parse(frow[0]);
            int K = int.Parse(frow[1]);

            int max = 0, currentmax = 0;
            int i = 1;
            int[] indexes = null;

            while(i < rows.Length)
            {
                if (int.Parse(rows[i]) > K)
                {
                    currentmax++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (currentmax > max)
                    {
                        max = currentmax;
                        indexes = new int[max];
                        indexes[--currentmax] = i;
                        do
                        {
                            indexes[--currentmax] = indexes[currentmax + 1] - 1;
                        } while (currentmax > 0);

                        currentmax = 0;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }

            if (indexes != null) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{max} occured on indexes {string.Join(",", indexes)} with values {string.Join(",", indexes.Select(i => rows[i]).ToList())}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] fRow = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int N = int.Parse(fRow[0]);
int K = int.Parse(fRow[1]);


bool isChain = false;
int currentFirstIndex = -1;
int maxFirstIndex = -1;
int currentLastIndex = -1;
int maxLastIndex = -1;
int currentLength = 0;
int maxLength = 0;

int[] H = new int[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   H[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   if(H[i] > K)
   {
      if (isChain)
      {
         currentLastIndex = i;
      }
      else
      {
         currentFirstIndex = i;
         isChain = true;
      }
      currentLength++;
   }
   else
   {
       if (maxLength < currentLength)
       {
          maxLength = currentLength;
          maxFirstIndex = currentFirstIndex;
          maxLastIndex = currentLastIndex;
       }
                       
       currentLength = 0;
       isChain = false;

    }
}

Console.WriteLine("first: " + maxFirstIndex + "    last: " + maxLastIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the way

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var firstLineInput = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ");
        var numberOfInput = Int64.Parse(firstLineInput[0]);
        var value = Int64.Parse(firstLineInput[1]);

        var startIndex = -1; //No value greater than value
        var endIndex = -1;

        var maxLength = 0;
        var maxStartIndex = -1;
        var maxEndIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInput ; i++)
        {
            var input = Int64.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            if (input > value && startIndex == -1)
            {
                startIndex = i;
                endIndex = i;

                if(maxLength == 0) 
                {
                    maxLength = 1;
                    maxStartIndex = startIndex;
                    maxEndIndex = endIndex;
                }
            }
            else if(input > value && startIndex != -1) 
            {
                endIndex = i;
            }
            else if(input < value) 
            {
                startIndex = -1;
                endIndex = -1;
            }

            if (maxLength < (endIndex - startIndex))
            {
                maxLength = endIndex - startIndex;
                maxStartIndex = startIndex;
                maxEndIndex = endIndex;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{maxStartIndex} {maxEndIndex}");
    }
```